# Spring-Flex Session Scope Service

Tags: apache-flex, spring, blazeds

I am using [Spring Flex project 1.5](http://static.springsource.org/spring-flex/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/). I wish to create a service with session scope.

```
@Service("storeService")
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
@RemotingDestination(channels = { "my-amf" })
public class StoreService implements IStoreService {
```

When I access the service, I got `No destination` error.

```
org.springframework.flex.core.DefaultExceptionLogger - The following exception occurred during request processing by the BlazeDS MessageBroker and will be serialized back to the client: 
flex.messaging.MessageException: No destination with id 'storeService' is registered with any service.
```

I have no issue if I do not annotate with @Scope, but it is singleton scope not session scope. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved after I changed proxyMode to `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS`.